# Ionic Google Map with directions(route) and distance

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I want to display google map with directions from source to destination where I will provide latitude and longitude values of source and destinations. And also display the distance between two places in the page.
I want to do this in ionic.

How can i do this ?

Help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather broad, but I would recommend you take a look at [this article by Nic Raboy](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/), it shows you in the article or even as a video how to implement Google Maps in Ionic.

Your other requirements (the latitude and longitude of source and destination) you can build by taking a look at the official Google Maps Javascript API documentation, specifically [for directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) and [for distances](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix).

If you have any further questions please post them in the comments, but otherwise if you for example are running into issues and have some code to show, please write a new question.